# Delayed function calling inside QgsTask

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, pyqt5

I try to add a function to the qt event loop via `QTimer.singleShot(...)` from within a `QgsTask`. However the function is never executed. I wrote a short script that isolates this issue:

```py
import time
from functools import partial

class TestTask(QgsTask):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('test task', QgsTask.CanCancel)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        QTimer.singleShot(10, partial(QgsMessageLog.logMessage, 'this message will NOT show up in the message log'))
        time.sleep(1)
        return True

def start_task():
    task = TestTask()
    QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)

    return task

t = start_task()
QTimer.singleShot(10, partial(QgsMessageLog.logMessage, 'this message will show up in the message log'))
```

My guess is this happens due to the fact that [threads do not have their own event loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3375211), but I could be mistaken. I've looked around to find a way to add an event loop to a `QgsTask` / to add a function to the main event loop but could not find anything.

How can I schedule the execution of a function in a `QgsTask` without relying on `QTimer`?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.